# Import RSA key pair on smart card using C#

Tags: .net, rsa, smartcard, pkcs#12

Is it possible to use `ImportParameters` method of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to import a key pair on a smart card?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I don't know the answer, but I guess it depends on the smart card. Normally however smart cards are personalized by a special application or in the factory and crypto libraries then make use of the signing / decryption services offered by the smart card. So it's not likely that this will work.

Comment: Yes, but the crypto service provider, should provide apis to programmatically import a certificate and i assumed that ImportParameters is a wrapper to that(whichever the store-hardware token, windows store etc). It seems like it doesn't since I get Invalid flags specified exception when I try to use Microsoft Base Smartcard Crypto Provider.

Answer (score 0):

[You can import a key from an XML String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring.aspx)

[You can also use a secure key container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tswxhw92.aspx)

Go through these articles, Hope this will help you.